# How can I post webform block values to another form?

Tags: webforms

I have a capture form in a block on a panel, and I am trying to get it to post the values to another form, once it is submitted.

How can I achieve this?

First name, last name, and email get posted to example.com/page?fname=XXX&lname=YYY&email=ZZZ.

I am using Drupal 6, and the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module version 3.9.

Comment: What module handles what you call, "another form"?

Comment: Yes, i have a module that is rendering a join form ...

Comment: I mean which one: a custom module, a Drupal core module, or a module that can be downloaded from Drupal.org. In the last two cases, knowing exactly which module is could be relevant.

Comment: It is a custom module ... and here is an example of how i am building the form ... http://pastie.org/3490496

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use one of the webform hooks to pass $_GET values via redirect.

```
function YOURMODULE_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission) {
  if ($node->nid == XXX){
    // Grab the values we need and create our get url parameter string. 
    $queryString = 'f1=' . $submission['value']['myfield'] . '&f2=' . $submission['value']['myfield2'] . '&f3=' . $submission['value']['myfield2'];
    drupal_goto('PATH/TO/FORM', $queryString);
  }
}
```

Or you can use a hook_form_alter for that form, add a new submit callback, and in the new function set the form's #redirect with the same syntax.

```
$queryString = $form_state['value']['myfield'] . '&f2=' . $form_state['value']['myfield2'] . '&f3=' . $form_state['value']['myfield2'];
$form['#redirect'] = array('PATH/TO/FORM', $queryString);
```

Then in your custom form, check for the $_GET values, and set them as the defaults to the appropriate fields, if they exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `#value` property of the relevant elements based on the `$_GET` values.

Comment: Right, but how to i get the webform to post those value to the url?

Comment: I shouldn't have talked about `$_GET`, but about `$_POST`, which is the variable used. It may not be usable though, given your sample code above. Maybe setting variables in `$_SESSION` would be a better way to go.